# What is the equivalent of Resource management in IOS swift?

Tags: ios

In Android there is a recycle view and you can use resource management to load the data and it all depends on the limit.

For example, what I want to do in IOS, is to have a table view cell and limit it to only 5 items per scroll. The reason why I'm doing this is to not load the data all at once. I want to load the data 5 per 5.

What is the equivalent of resource Management in Android to IOS??

Comment: UITableView does exactly that out of the box.

Comment: Can you the answer and some sample code so that I could accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views like UITableView, UICollectionView, and viewControllers like UIPageViewController and UITabBarController are already optimized for performance and resource use. In general they will only load what is necessary to create the on-screen content.

Each class is optimized in a different way. UITabBarController initializes each embedded ViewController, but their views are not loaded until you select the tab of a ViewController. UIPageViewController preloads and caches the next or previous viewController as soon as you start scrolling.

UITableView will reuse its cells. The tableView will create an initial set of cells to fill the screen. After that cells are reused, if all your cells are of the same reuseIdentifier and their height is the same the maximum number of cells that are kept in memory is the number needed to fill the screen + 1. During cell reuse a cell is placed in a cache as soon as it moves off-screen. When the next cell is needed it is taken from that cache.

This is done automatically if you do a few things like setting the same reuseIdentifier for the same cell.
You have to keep in mind that each cell will be displayed multiple times, so you have to adjust your code accordingly. For example you generally don't want to add views to the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, because it can and will be called multiple times. You should design your views for maximum reusability and create UITableViewCell subclasses where you add those views in the `init` of the cell.

The best way to explore all this is to create a bunch of test projects which are spiked with logging code. For example to see reuse in UITableView:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        println("init Cell")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    deinit {
        println("deinit Cell")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        if let text = textLabel!.text {
            println("prepareForReuse of cell with text \"\(text)\"")
        }
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = 130 // we don't need 15 cells on screen to demonstrate how that works
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        println("Display Cell \(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Which after loading leads to this console output:

```
init Cell
Display Cell 0
init Cell
Display Cell 1
init Cell
Display Cell 2
init Cell
Display Cell 3
init Cell
Display Cell 4
init Cell
Display Cell 5
```

Once you scroll cells are reused (the first init is that +1 cell that is necessary because the index=6 cell is visible before the index=0 cell went off-screen):

```
init Cell
Display Cell 6
prepareForReuse of cell with text "Cell 0"
Display Cell 7
prepareForReuse of cell with text "Cell 1"
Display Cell 8
```